# What is this opening in my dishwasher's pump housing tray?

Tags: dishwasher

What is that hole in the sump there for and what could cause a leak from there?

It's a Bosch dishwasher model #SHE53TL5UC/01

I appreciate your help.

[image: picture of a sump highlighting a mystery hole which looks like part of an overflow tray on the top of the sump]

Comment: I would imagine part of the rubber seal is leaking near the hole.  It might be an alignment hole so the part goes in the right place/location so everything lines up.

Comment: 100% agree with @crip659 - while the water may be coming out of that hole, that isn't where the leak is. Seems to be a lot of junk on the o-ring sealing surface.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. Your comments made me realize that for water to get to the hole it would have to leak past the o-ring. I'll replace the o-ring seal and add an extra sealing tube as well.  It seems like the hole is placing the water so that it will not to hit electronics and send the water to the area with the overflow sensor when leaking past the o-ring seal.

Comment: Don't add extra parts. Millions of dishwashers _don't_ leak there, so your problem is a tired gasket or debris. Extra parts probably won't fit or work and may actually cause problems.

Comment: @isherwood. Sorry for not knowing the proper way to use the site. Fair concern about extra parts. The part I'm referring to is an extra tube sold by Bosch to help ensure the proper functioning of the gasket. Here's a link: https://www.bosch-home.com/us/shop-productlist/12005744#/Tabs=section-fitsappliance/Togglebox=manuals/.

Comment: There's not much information on that page. I get the impression that it's just a replacement gasket. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It’s essentially a replacement gasket that can be installed without removing the current gasket or disassembling the dishwasher.